# Cant access data after realloc struct vector

Tags: c, vector, struct, realloc

I'm using `realloc`to reduce the size of my vector. I want to loose the last position only. so, if I have 10 positions and I use `realloc` to allocate enough space for `9 * sizeof(my_struct)` will the vector get truncated and keep the old data but the last position ? I thought it was right, but when I try to print the value after the realloc I get `Segmentation Fault` error. Here is my code:

```
    //Instanciate the vector
    my_struct *struc;
    my_struct *buffer;

    //Allocate space for 10 slots
    struc = (my_struct *) malloc(10 * sizeof(my_struct));

    //realloc for 9 slots
    buffer = (my_struct *) realloc(struc, 9 * sizeof(my_struct));        
    if(buffer != NULL){
       struc = buffer;
    }
```

now if I try to use `printf` to check the elements inside the vector, I get `Segmentaition Fault`

OBS: The Vector has been filled up with data BEFORE the realloc. I didnt post here because I think it's unnecessary... Imagine the vector already with data in this code.

Comment: The code you've posted looks OK. There is probably already heap corruption due to another bug in your program. To get better help, [follow the instructions to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks. What about my thought, is it right? If I reallocate from 10 slots to 9 will  I lose only the last one ? The rest of the data will be ok allocated?

Comment: Yes that's how it works.

Comment: Indeed! I've just tested it with a simple struct with only an integer field, and `realloc` works as expected (although it didn't really change the buffer address which I find logical).

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix SO after all I have to `free(buffer)` right?

Comment: As `buffer` and `struc` point to the same memory region (remember, you just made `struc = buffer`) you can free any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data can be *moved* by `realloc()`. So if there is any pointer to the data, after the call, such pointers would become invalid.

Comment: So after `realloc` I cant access: `my_struct[0].Name`  is there was already data on it? Is there a solution for that? Do I have to call a function to fill it again ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro did you mean `struc[0].Name`? Yes you can access that. What you can't do is `my_struct *ptr = &struc[0]; ` , then your realloc code, then access `ptr->Name`.

Comment: Got the error. Thank you sir! I wrote it right but the original code I was using the wrong parameter for realloc. ;s